# Stack global project with hdevtools

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hdevtools

`hevtools` can find modules imported in a Stack project, but it can't find packages that I have `stack import`ed outside of a project.  Do I need to tell it where the packages are somehow?

Thanks